# How to open modal by click <img > id

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a images gallery, I want to open a modal by click image and show images details like name, title, and description, I tried to alert message

```
<img class="enent_inst" id="myImg" style="width:100%;" alt="<?php echo 
$events[$j]['title']; ?>" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/Event_gallary/<? 
php echo $events[$j]['event_image']; ?>" />
```

js side

```
$(document).on('click','#myImg',function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: i'm guessing an image gallery consists of multiple images right? probably use a class instead

Comment: There's no actual question in the post, what's going wrong?

Comment: i tried also class bt not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `$events[$j]['event_image']` we could see clearly that your posted code runs inside a loop, so that will construct an invalid HTML structure with duplicate identifier in the same document, what will lead your event to point always on the first element with `#myImg` identifier.

Isuggest to use a common class instead to avoid duplicate `id`'s :

```
<img class="enent_inst" class="myImg" style="width:100%;" ...
```

In your JS code use class selector `.myImg` instead :

```
$(document).on('click','.myImg',function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Define your Modal in your HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

                <button  class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then bind your modal to a button

```
 <button title="OPEN MODAL type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the image data(title, name, ...) in data attributes:

```
<img class="enent_inst" ... data-title="title" data-name="name" ... />
```

When you click on the image, you can access this data and set it in a modal:

```
$(document).on('click','#myImg',function(){
    title = $(this).data('title');
    name = $(this).data('name');

    ... open modal and set title, name, ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert a counter to `while` loop:

```
$i = 0;

while (...) {
   ... // any code here

   $i++;
}
```

Change id by image to data-target: `data-target="myImg_<?php echo $i; ?>` (output e.g.: myImg_1

and call modal (with id e.g. myImg_1) with jQuery:

```
$('enent_inst').click(funltion(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var modal = $(this).data("target");
   $(modal).modal('show'); 
});
```